# Redirected homepage as shell page rather than the index page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am relateively new to angularJS. AngularJS being typically suited to Single Page Application scenario, most of the login examples i find define the index.html as the shell page meaning the ng-view is defined within the index.html.

The Problem : In my scenario the Login page and the index page are the same i.e. when you hit the root context you land up at the login.html and once you login successfully you reach the homepage.html. The homepage would have a Logo, Top Banner, Left Navigation and a content section. The different templates would simply sit inside the content section rest remaining the same giving different views like the dashboard view, enquiry form view, reports view etc. So it is more suitable for me to make the homepage.html as the shell page since all other views will be just embedded in the homepage.

Now how do i redirect from the login page to the homepage which is the shell-page because as per my understanding

```
<body ng-app></body>
```

would make the login page the shell page and once the login.html is a shell page it cannot be redefined.

other way is having a blank shell page and having the entire login page as one view and dashboard.html as another view and similarly enquiry.html, reports.html and different templates. But that is not a good approach since i will have to duplicate the code for top banner, navigation etc in each template. Doing so will defeat the basic purpose of SPA.

How to achieve this ? It would be good to have a dummy example if possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider how you build your index.html page

Your index page musn't be a login page/home page. It must be a container that will contains each of them depending on the current routes.

so basically an index page would be

```
<body ng-app="app">
    [an header maybe ?]
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script></script>//all script at end of page
<body>
```

Then you define route that will say that something that /login will match to login.html as the content of the ng-view. /home will match to homepage.html.

Unknown route will match to /login ($routerProvider.otherwise). And in your login page if your user is already connected you can redirect him to homepage.

On all others pages, if the user is not connected you change the current route toward the login one. For this take a look at the event $routeChangeSuccess in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: I understand your point that i must define a route for login and another route for home but consider that the home page would have so much of code for top banner, left navigation, footer, quick access bar on top left etc. all these must be permanently available across all other views like enquiry.html, reports.html etc. I would have to duplicate the html for these. Any solution for this. The purpose is to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Put it on index page wrapped on some div tag and hide it (ng-hide) when you're on login page ? This is what i did for a sidepanel on my application

Comment: you mean to say i should hide the common components like top banner, left nav etc when we have a login view. Yes that could be an alternative. But is it not possible to somehow load index.html/login.html outside the SPA environment and the SPA routing only kicks in once the login is successful

Comment: Yes it is. Just use two different html page that include your javascript module and so on on each of them. So basically you will have a "**Double Page Application**", not necessary shocking to me. When login is succesfull just perform a redirect to your homepage.

Comment: You mean to say if i include ng-app in two different html pages i should be able to create a Double Page Application. If thats the case it is a more cleaner solution. I would rather have two different modules one as ng-app="loginModule" and the other as ng-app="myApplication" this way i will not load the same js twice and also maintain seperation of concerns. It would be good to have a working example of this approach. I would update this once i get a working example. Anyways Thanks alot

Comment: This is something that i did once, my client didn't want do load all javascript off all page (some google map on one module, ....) so i cut my application in one page per "section" of navigation, making it look it it was a single page, but it wasn't behind the scene :)